# copiar imagen canvas delphi fmx

Tags: canvas, delphi, pascal, bitmap, gdi

Queria consultar cual es procedimiento equivalente en Firemonkey al
metodo (**Copyrect o StretchDraw**) del canvas de la VCL.

He utilizado copybitmap, pero no logro copiar la imagen al formulario.

```
Canvas.StretchDraw(Rect(0, 0, Width, Height), MyBitMap)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno creo que viendo un ejemplo por la web, logre utilizar el canvas. En definitiva, el StretchDraw no funciona como método en fmx, por lo menos yo no lo pude utilizar.

Pero para lo que estoy realizando y experimentando, me pude hacer con el método DrawBitmap, especificando los tamaños y origines.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Me alegra que hayas encontrado la solución. Creo que vendría bien que agregues algo de código a tu respuesta, para que si alguien pasa por aquí en el futuro encuentre la fórmula que anda buscando. No olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada cuando te lo permita el sistema. Si solo sirve en tu caso, quizás venga bien que edites la pregunta y aclares cual es ese caso especial, para dar lugar a que pueda haber una nueva pregunta en el futuro sobre el tema sin que se duplique con esta. Para más información, mira [answer]. Un saludo.